# RoR callback after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback

I have 2 models User and Profile

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_one :profile
  after_create :create_profile
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My problem is that

```
after_create: create_profile
```

doesn't work, because does not pass validation. Does rail have something **after_create: create_profile!** or **after_create (validate: false): create_profile** to skip validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  after_create :create_profile!

  private
  def create_profile!
    profile = Profile.new(user_id: self.id)
    profile.save(validate: false)
  end
```

I tried to do this.
Another solution that has occurred is to set default values to the database.

Answer (score 0):

After_create will work in controller not in model. 
create a method in controller which gets called on after_create action.
in that method call the Model method to create a profile.
Its not good to skip the validations but if you want to, You can still do it.
In the profile model, you can add a flag to skip the validation on call from this method.

Comment: If I remove validation in Profile model, after_create will work in the User model

Comment: Yes, but that's not the right way. Better have a flag to skip validation